# Trying to get custom js files in my admin header

Tags: wp-admin, wp-enqueue-script, actions, wp-register-script

I'm trying to add a java script file to my admin header and use admin-ajax.php to use ajax in my wp-admin (still learning a lot about the process).  I've created a custom folder in my theme_directory/js called custom with the file I need to add to the admin header but it doesn't seem to be working.  here's the code:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_enqueue_scripts');

function my_admin_enqueue_scripts() {
    global $current_screen;
    if ( 'page' != $current_screen->ID )
        return;
    wp_register_script('my-scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom/my-scripts.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script('my-scripts');
    wp_localize_script('my-scripts', 'wp_ajax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
}
```

Despite this I'm not seeing a reference in my header to my custom js file.  I've even tried `add_action('admin_header', 'my_admin_enqueue_scripts');` with no avail.   I only need this script file in my wp-admin.

What am I missing?  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahh ok I figured it out while researching.  I needed to add the $hook parameter and pass it to my function like so:

```
function my_admin_enqueue_scripts($hook) {
    global $current_screen;

    if ( 'post.php' != $hook )
        return;
    wp_register_script('my-scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom/my-scripts.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script('my-scripts');
    wp_localize_script('my-scripts', 'wp_ajax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
}
```

This gave me the results I was looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

it's not admin_header but admin_head for add action. I finf it better to put js in admin_footer.